# Hover not working in HTML/CSS example

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS. This is an example directly taken from Jon Duckett's book.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #111111;}
        table {
            width: 600px;}
        th, td {
            padding: 7px 10px 10px 10px;}
        th {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
            font-size: 90%;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #111111;
            border-top: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: left;}
        tr.even {
            background-color: #efefef;}
        tr.hover {
            background-color: #c3e6e5;}
        .money {
            text-align: right;}     

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>First Edition Auctions</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th class="money">Reserve Price</th>
                <th class="money">Current Bid</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E.E. Cummings</td>
                <td>Tulips & Chimneys</td>
                <td class="money">$2,000.00</td>
                <td class="money">$2,642.50</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>Charles d'Orleans</td>
                <td>Poemes</td>
                <td class="money"></td>
                <td class="money">$5,866.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>T.S. Eliot</td>
                <td>Poems 1909 - 1925</td>
                <td class="money">$1,250.00</td>
                <td class="money">$8,499.35</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="even">
                <td>Sylvia Plath</td>
                <td>The Colossus</td>
                <td class="money"></td>
                <td class="money">$1,031.72</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can view the output [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4v2rob9/), with the `hover` there also not working.

It looks like [the example on his website](http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-14/table-properties.html) works fine. I'm not sure what I did wrong in my code. It looks fine.

Browser I'm using is Chrome 48.0.2564.97.

Comment: did you mean tr:hover?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:hover` is a pseudo-class.

It is preceded by a colon (`:`) not a period (`.`)

Answer (score 1):

Use :hover instead of .hover (`.hover` matches tag with `class="hover"`)

```
tr:hover {
    background-color: #c3e6e5;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you called out a class instead of declaring a state.

```
tr.hover {background-color: #c3e6e5;}
```

Should be

> tr:hover {background-color: #c3e6e5;}

The period in your original version calls out a class that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It should read

tr:hover {background-color: #c3e6e5;}

not

tr.hover {background-color: #c3e6e5;}